# "I like to read by/with the light of the candle." Which is right?

Tags: prepositions

> I like to read by/with the light of the candle.

Which one do you say or write?

Comment: I would write: _I like to read **by** candlelight_. However, the truth is: _I like to read **with** the lights on_.

Comment: I think of it this way: "I like to read by candlelight." is *by* because if you were actually doing that, the candle would probably be next/near to you. In "I like to read with the lights on.", they are just on somewhere in the room as they are brighter, so *with* is OK.

Answer (score 2):

The more idiomatic answer is "by." This is a special case used to describe a light source. It would also be more idiomatic to say "by candlelight" rather than "by the light of a candle," unless you wanted to emphasize that there was only a single candle.

Any light source should be used with "by," and any activity, not just reading. For example, Shakespeare:

> Ill-met by moonlight, proud Titania.

and Victor Hugo (in translation, of course):

> So be it: I will die by starlight.

"With" would not be idiomatic in most English dialects.

However, this is only the case if the light source is the object of the preposition "by." You can add an adjective to the light source, or add additional prepositional phrases to the end, and still use "by":

> He read it by the flickering light of the candelabra, held high over his head.
>
> I prefer to read the Necronomicon by the light of a single black tallow candle.

But a noun phrase with an independent verb is generally preceded by "with," not "by":

> He read it with the candelabra held high over his head.
>
> I prefer to read the Necronomicon with only a single candle lit.

Comment: do you agree on this - *I'd like to read **in** candle light?*

Answer (score 0):

> I like to read by the light of the candle.

Is fine technically if you're trying to be overly poetic or dramatic.  It wouldn't be used in everyday speech though.

> I like to read with the light of the candle.

Is also fine but puts a slight emphasis on the candle's light.

Comment: In your first example you're correct that it's poetic, and *the* makes sense. In your second example, though, it would be "*a* candle", not "*the* candle".

Comment: Thanks.Nonetheless, what do you say in everyday English?

Comment: Assuming you mean read by light produced by candles, as opposed to being physically next to a candle, as a single candle is not practical for reading, I would casually say "I like to read by candlelight."  If I were to hear this, I would assume many candles are used to produce reading light.

Answer (score 0):

- *by the candle light*, means near the light of a candle.

  - *with the light of a candle* means using the light of a candle.

The are both correct but sound a bit old in usage since we no longer use a candle light to read.

Personally I'd use **by a candle light**

Answer (score 0):

I use *by* in this case.

It sounds strange to my ear to say "I read with candle light", but sounds correct to say "I read with a candle". The probably has to do with the candle being a tool that I'm using (and thus similar to, say, "I read with glasses"), whereas the light is distinct from the candle (similarly, I would say "I read *by* moonlight").

Answer (score 0):

"By the light of a candle."  That is much preferred to `with`.

(But note to `the` before `candle` when discussing preferences in general.)